# How to select from a parameter (cursor,varchar2, etc)

Tags: oracle, select

I have a little problem and if you could help me it would be great.

```
DECLARE
      CURSOR cur1 IS 
         SELECT table_name 
           FROM all_tab_columns 
          WHERE column_name LIKE 'DESCRIPTION';
      tableName varchar2(100);
BEGIN
      OPEN cur1;
      LOOP
        FETCH cur1 INTO tableName;
        EXIT WHEN cur1%NOTFOUND;
        dbms_output.put_line(tablename);
      END LOOP;
END;
```

What I need is to get all the information possible from those tables with the condition:

```
WEHRE DESCRIPTION LIKE 'Transaction%'
```

Something like this

```
SELECT *
  FROM tableName ---- from above
 WEHRE DESCRIPTION LIKE 'Transaction%'
```

I would like to select all data from the tables in my cursor.

The tables don't have the same structure, one can have 4 coloumns, one can have 10 coloumns.

Can it be done in an anonymous block? 
Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: You can generate the `SELECT` with dynamic SQL, but what do you want to do with the rows selected from each table?

Comment: I just wanna display them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE
      CURSOR cur1 IS 
         SELECT table_name 
           FROM user_tab_columns 
          WHERE column_name LIKE 'DESCRIPTION';
      tableName varchar2(100);
      l_description varchar2(100);
      l_str_val varchar2(100) := 'Transaction%';
      l_cursor sys_refursor;
BEGIN
      OPEN cur1;
      LOOP
        FETCH cur1 INTO tableName;
        EXIT WHEN cur1%NOTFOUND;
        open l_cursor for 'select DESCRIPTION from ' || tableName || ' where DESCRIPTION like :description' using l_str_val;
        loop
          fetch l_cursor into l_description; 
          exit when l_cursor%NOTFOUND;
          dbms_output.put_line(tablename || '  ' || l_description);
        end loop;
        close l_cursor;
      END LOOP;
      close cur1;
END;
```

I extracted only description column, because I am sure this column is in the table, if you want to extract more columns you have to rewrite this like:

```
WHERE column_name = ('DESCRIPTION', 'ID', NAME)
```

and then:

```
execute immediate 'select DESCRIPTION, ID, NAME from ' || tableName || ' where DESCRIPTION like :description' into l_description, l_id, l_name using l_str_val;
```

Comment: Let's say that my description is 'Transaction' and in my first table this description isn't found but in the following 3 tables it is found. This script shuts down because the select on the first table doesn't return data, and the error for that shut down is ORA-01403: no data found. Can i pass by this some how? By this shut down, the script doesn't select from 2nd or 3rd or Nth table.

Comment: Check my answer now, I forgot how to close a cursor.